# Modifying the Correlation ID Screen

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error-handling

I want to modify the Correlation message that is shown to the users when a correlation id occurs. I need to give them information to contact IT as well as being able to call a JavaScript API when the problem occurs so that we can take some proactive steps.

EDIT: What is the name of the page in the layouts folder which shows the correlation id?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

The page is "error.aspx" in "_layouts" folder.

Comment: So if I change this page it will affect all site collections and this is where I can implement my custom logic "On Correlation". Makes sense?

Comment: Yes it will, to do this though do bit edit the file in the hive, but make a duplicate layouts folder and remap it in iis. Editing hive files invalidates your Warranty.